# How do I solve distance and city calculator using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, algorithm

I am trying to create a code that will solve the CCC 2018 J3 Problem "Are We there Yet?".

There are 5 cities, and would like to calculate the distance per city.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14SNf.png)

Expected output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfASg.png)

Link: https://cemc.math.uwaterloo.ca/contests/computing/past_ccc_contests/2018/stage%201/juniorEF.pdf

My code is this:

```
 /// GET/api/J3/DistanceCalculator/{distance1}/{distance2}/{distance3}/{distance4} 
    /// api/J3/DistanceCalculator/3/10/12/5 
    /// Output:
    /// First Line: 0/3/13/25/30 -> 0 is the distance of the current destination
    /// Second Line: 3/0/10/22/27
    /// Third Line: 13/10/0/12/17
    /// Fourth Line: 25/22/12/0/5
    /// Fifth Line: 30/27/17/5/0
    /// </example>

    // GET api/J3/DistanceCalculator/{distance1}/{distance2}/{distance3}/{distance4}/
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/J3/DistanceCalculator/{distance1}/{distance2}/{distance3}/{distance4}")]
    
    public int DistanceCalculator(int distance1, int distance2, int distance3, int distance4)
    {
        //declare variables and array
        List <int> cities = new List<int> {5};
        List <int> distances = new List<int> {4};
        int currentDistance = 0;

        //loop representing 5 different starting points of 5 cities
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {

            

            //write distance[i]
            //Debug.WriteLine("You are starting in city: " + i);

            //start at 0 since city 1 is starting point
            int cities[0] =  0;
            //continue adding distance per number given
            int cities[i] = cities[i - 1] + distances[i-1];
             
            return cities[i+1] + " " + cities[i+2] + " " + cities[i+3] + " " + cities[i+4] + " " + cities[i+5]; 

            //Debug.WriteLine("East-------------");
            //Debug.WriteLine("You are starting in city: " + i + " and driving to city 0");distances[

            int distances[i] = cities[i + 1] - cities[i]; 


            //create a loop calculating the distance of the city from the original destination
            for (int j = i; j >= 0; j--)
            {
                int formerDistance = cities[j] - cities[j - 1];
                //Debug.WriteLine("The distance from previous city is " + j);

                //convert negative numbers into positive
                if (formerDistance < 0)
                {
                    formerDistance *= -1;
                }
                else
                {
                    formerDistance *= 1;
                }

                //print
                return formerDistance;
            }


            //show former distance 
            return formerDistances;

            //Debug.WriteLine("West--------------");
            //Debug.WriteLine("You are started in city: " + i + " and driving to city 4");

            //calculates the city from the starting point
            for (int j = i; j < 5; j++)
            {
                distances[j + 1] = distances[j] + distances[j + 1];

                int city5 = 0;
                int city4 = distances[j-1] - city5;
                int city3 = distances[j - 1] - city4;
                int city2 = distances[j - 1] - city5;
                int city1 = distances[j - 1] - city2;

                //Debug.WriteLine("The distance from previous city is " + i);
                
                //Debug.WriteLine("You are starting in city: " + j);

            }


        }
        currentDistance = distance1 + distance2 + distance3 + distance4;

        //return the distance
        return currentDistance;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your code work the way you expect, if not, what problems are you having? This is a question and answer site; without a question, you won't get an answer. Note that you have this setup as web app, in general returning an integer is not something web apps usually do. Do you really want to return a single integer after that calculation?

Comment: Unfortunately my initial code is not working. Yes I am aware that webapps should be used as backend, Flydog57. I did J1 and J2 problems using C# as part of my assignment. Now I'm trying to solve a J3 problem. I would do it in JavaScript if I had the chance. But we're just trying to learn how to do variables and make if/else statements using C# Asp.net. Thank you for your help and comment though!

Comment: _"Not Working"_ still isn't a good problem description. What's "working"? What's not (and why do you say that it's not working)? What are you seeing when you debug your code? I'm not trying to give you a hard time, I'm trying to coach you on asking a better question.  And I don't care if you want to use C# or Javascript or Fortran. It's just that it's a bit weird to see a simple integer being returned from a web endpoint, particularly when the problem description talked about _"the distance per city"_

Answer (score 1):

Let's split the initial problem into smaller ones:

1. Read initial data
2. Solve for one line
3. Solve for the table
4. Output the solution

Let me use console to solve the problem; you can adapt it for REST, WinForms etc.

```
using System.Linq;

...

private static int[] ReadData() => Console
  .ReadLine()
  .Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
  .Select(item => int.Parse(item))
  .ToArray();
```

Solve for one line (let it be line #`index`):

```
private static int[] Distances(int[] value, int index) {
  int[] result = new int[value.Length + 1];

  for (int i = index - 1; i >= 0; --i) 
    result[i] = value[i] + result[i + 1];

  for (int i = index + 1; i < result.Length; ++i)
    result[i] = value[i - 1] + result[i - 1];

  return result;
}
```

Solve for the entire table:

```
private static int[][] AllDistances(int[] value) => Enumerable
  .Range(0, data.Length + 1)
  .Select(i => Distances(data, i))
  .ToArray();
```

Output

```
private static void PrintSolution(int[][] value) => Console
  .WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, value
     .Select(line => string.Join(" ", line))));
```

Finally, let's combine it all together

```
private static void Main() {
  int[] data = ReadData();

  int[][] table = AllDistances(data);

  PrintSolution(table);
}
```

Comment: Alright I will try this one! Thank you Dmitry! I learned a lot from you

Answer (score 0):

I think it's good to apply the permutations problem from algebra lesson.

Hence:

distance[i+1] += distance[i];

and then with extracting the solution from city3-city2 for example, use

(distance[j] - distance[i]);

to get distance 2.